# How can to send POST via socket.io or call a feathersjs service via socket.io?

Tags: node.js, socket.io, feathersjs

I have a service (find, get, create, remove) and I would like to call theme via socket.io

For example:

A user writes a message on the chat to another user. I would like to the data not sending via request but in realtime on socket because in this moment creating is a document of mongoose.

Is it posible? If yes, how can I do it?

Below is my snippet code: (Server side)

```
 io.on('connect', function(socket){

   socket.on('message', function(id, msg){
   socket.to(id).emit('chat message', msg);
   });

}))
```

http://localhost:3030/messages <-- URL of REST api to creating a document with mongoose. After sending data on the link is creating a document. I need that a document will be create via socket.io, not request.

I mean something like this:

```
 io.on('connect', function(socket){

   socket.on('message', function(id, msg){
   socket.to(id).emit('chat message', msg);

   // Socket call a create method of my service
   socket.post('/messages', data);

   });

}))
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are not using [Feathers as the client](https://docs.feathersjs.com/clients/feathers.html) you can find the detailed documentation about how to call services via sockets [here](https://docs.feathersjs.com/clients/vanilla-socket-io.html#calling-service-methods).

A messages for the `/messages` service can be created directly via a socket like this:

```
var socket = io();

socket.emit('messages::create', {
  "text": "I really have to iron"
}, (error, message) => {
  console.log('Todo created', message);
});
```

You can also listen to any created event like this:

```
var socket = io();

socket.on('messages created', data => console.log('Someone created a new message', data);

socket.emit('messages::create', {
  "text": "I really have to iron"
}, (error, message) => {
  console.log('Todo created', message);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, yes and no. There are no HTTP/REST-style verbs in Socket.io but since you can send anything you want, you can add the verbs yourself.

Additionally if you want to have a more structured way of building real-time APIs then you may want to take a look at frameworks like ActionHerp:

- https://www.actionherojs.com/

In addition to HTTP, it can use WebSocket or TCP sockets as the underlying transport, and you can create custom "actions" that you can customize to your needs.

Now, if you want to use Feathers and you don't want to use anything else, then you may take a look at feathers-socketio:

- https://www.npmjs.com/package/feathers-socketio

It's a Feathers Socket.io real-time API provider that exposes Feathers services through a Socket.io real-time API. It is compatible with Feathers 1.x and 2.x. And you can use Socket.io to interact with it.

Comment: I use a feathersjs, I do not want to add anything else. You can say that I have a complete a project. I need only send a data.

Comment: I have a socket.io implemented in my project. I mean something else. I updated my question.